# Which functions in the Android Bionic grant access to hardware (camera, microphone, etc.)?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-source, bionic

I am writing a code that requires changing the functions in the Bionic that access resources such as the camera, microphone, location, contacts, and more (for academic research purposes).

I am having a hard time finding these functions, since there is barely any documentation on-line.

Could anyone provide information about the names/locations of those functions?

Comment: Very vague question. Can you be more specific? Do you want to know how HAL/HIDL work in Android, or you just want to find some uapi headers in bionic/ dir?

Comment: @SamProtsenko My target is modifying the Android OS so that applications that are trying to access the hardware, for example, the camera, will receive a different image then usual, but will not notice the difference. which code would you recommend for me to modify? is it a part of HAL? where could it be found?

Comment: The features you mention are not handled by **bionic**. Some (like sound) have public NDK API (Open SL), others, like location or contacts, have not. If your purpose is to modify the platform to fake camera input, you can learn how this is done for Emulator in AOSP sources.